# Application executable name is different from vshost executable name

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, visual-studio-debugging, csproj

I have a problem where my vshost.exe filename is different from my actual application.exe filename, preventing me from debugging the application.

The setup is as follows:

```
- MySolution
    - Installer.Release
    - Installer.Debug
    - Installer.Testing
    - MyApplication
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, .NET 4.0 and InstallShield LE.

Now, for reasons beyond my control it was decided that the application executable name should contain the environment: `MyApplication (Release).exe`, `MyApplication (Debug).exe`, `MyApplication (Testing).exe`.

This is easily done by modifying the `.csproj` file to the following:

```
<AssemblyName>MyApplication (Release)</AssemblyName>
<AssemblyName Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">MyApplication (Debug)</assemblyName>
<AssemblyName Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Testing'">MyApplication (Testing)</AssemblyName>
```

When building the application in `Debug` it generates the following files in my `bin/Debug` folder:

```
MyApplication (Debug).exe
MyApplication (Debug).exe.config
MyApplication (Debug).vshost.exe
MyApplication (Debug).vshost.manifest
```

So far so good.

When building the application in `Testing`, it generates the following files in my `bin/Testing` folder:

```
MyApplication (Testing).exe
MyApplication (Testing).exe.config
MyApplication (Debug).vshost.exe
MyApplication (Debug).vshost.manifest
```

As you can see, the vshost files that are generated are named differently, which causes Visual Studio to throw the following error when trying to debug:

> Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target
>   'D:\Code\MySolution\MyApplication\bin\Testing\MyApplication (Debug).exe'
>   is missing. Please build the project and retry, or set the OutputPath
>   and AssemblyName properties appropriately to point at the correct
>   location for the target assembly.

Interestingly, if I change the `AssemblyName` of the `Debug` configuration to `MyApplication (Foo)`, then the vhost files in the `Testing` folder are also renamed to `MyApplication (Foo)`. So something is forcing the use of my `Debug` configuration onto my `Testing` configuration. But what?

Currently I can work around it by launching the application and then attaching the Visual Studio debugger, but it's wasting my time. It's also not a problem when building the installer, because the vshost files are simply ignored.

So far Google has not been really helpful. Most of the search results explain what a vshost file is and how it works but that's not what I need. I need to know why the vshost files are named differently and how I can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround can be to disable the vshost option:

Go to Project + Properties, Debug tab, un-check the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" option.